# git перенести данные

Tags: git

Использую git через windows git bash, мне нужно перенести файлы в папку, я могу перекинуть иконки в нужную папку, тогда в гит статусе у меня будут изменения: удаленный файл, не отслеживаемый файл. Кажется, что это не самое лучшее решение, подскажите как лучше это делать?

Comment: Логично - у Вас произошли изменения, эти изменения нужно "закрепить". да, нужно эти файлы добавить (и удаленные тоже, как бы это не звучало странно) и сделать обычный коммит. Если что, git bash, а не bush

Comment: или использовать команду `git mv`